What is the normal order of a transpositionally symmetric scale?
According to definition the normal order of a scale can be achieved as follows:

add the octave of the root note on top of the scale
find the size x of the biggest interval
find all y intervals of size x and by rotation produce y scales with the respective x-sized interval at the top
from these y scales choose the one with notes most tightly packed to the left

Let's consider the whole tone scale [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]:

Adding the octave of the root gives [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
the size of the biggest interval is 2
since every interval in the scale is 2 all rotations of the original scale become candidates
all of the candidates are packed equally tight to the left.

Now my question: Is the normal form not unique in that case, meaning each of the scales could be considered the normal form? Or is every transpositionally symmetrical scale (like the whole tone scale) its own normal order?

Part of the definition of normal order is that in case of a tie, the normal order begins with the lowest-numbered pitch class.1 That means that for a scale like the whole-tone scale, the normal form is [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, T] or [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, E].

1 See, for example https://musictheory.pugetsound.edu/mt21c/NormalForm.html.


In the event of an absolute tie, choose the set that begins on the smaller number.


